# Auto-generating a graphql schema for relay (Graphene server)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphene-python

I am new to Relay and am trying to put together my first app. I already have a GraphQL server (using Graphene) that is backed by a PostgreSQL DB via SQLAlchemy automap, and published as a Flask app. Now, I'm trying to put together the front end, and it looks like the relay-compiler is expecting a GraphQL schema file on the client-side. I'm wondering if there is a way to have this schema file be dynamically auto generated, and how that could be set up.

I'm using https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate as the starting point for my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After browsing around the Graphene codebase I found schema_printer in the utils module of graphql-python that gets the job done for me:

```
import json
from schema import schema
import sys
from graphql.utils import schema_printer

my_schema_str = schema_printer.print_schema(schema)
fp = open("schema.graphql", "w")
fp.write(my_schema_str)
fp.close()
```

Comment: How to run this script?

Answer (score 2):

For me, https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/introspection/ was helpful.
In my case schema was defined in the schema.py file of apiApp, and so the command to retrieve schema.json was as following.

```
./manage.py graphql_schema --schema apiApp.schema.schema --out schema.json
```